# Seaborn: Remove fit from distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a distribution with distplot(), and I want

1. absolute numbers instead of relative frequency on the y axis
2. no fitted function

I thought that (1) could be achieved by setting `norm_hist=False`, but still, relative frequencies are shown on the y axis:

[image: First try]

But no problem, I can work around that by directly setting the 'normed' keyword of the underlying pyplot.hist graph:

[image: Second try]

However, now I have the problem that the fitted function (created with pyplot.plot) still works on the normalized values and thus is somewhere on the bottom of the graph. I would like to completely get rid of the fitted plot. How do I do that? I thought setting `fit=None` would do the trick, but as you can see, it doesn't.

Any help is appreciated!

Lukas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line you call "fit" is a kernel density estimate (KDE), it only makes sense for a normalized plot (as it is a probability density function).

To get rid of the kde curve, you may use the `kde=False` keyword argument.

```
distplot( ... , kde=False)
```

Comment: D'Oh. That was too easy. Thank you!